# How can I express in a sentence something that happened in the past but that has an impact on the present?

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense, present-tense

Given that English is not my first language, I was wondering how to express a verb that started and ended in the past but that has a repercussion in the present moment...
Is it correct to say “spent my life developing the perfect recipe only managed to keep me away from my passion”?
(The sentence is just an example, but I hope it is sufficiently explanatory)

Comment: I don't think you understand the present perfect. If somebody "spent their life" doing something, the only reason you *couldn't* use the present perfect is if they're dead.

Comment: So “spent” is right only if the person is dead, otherwise is “have spent”? “Have spent my life developing the perfect recipe only managed to keep me away from my passion” is correct...?

Comment: _'spent my life developing the perfect recipe only managed to keep me away from my passion'_ is not a sentence. Do you mean _spending_ so that _spending my life developing the perfect recipe_ is the subject of the verb _managed_? Then your question is about whether it should be _managed_ or has _managed_.

Comment: Yes! I would like to express the spending of my life as the subject of the sentence! So it is correct if I say “spending my life developing the perfect recipe has only managed to...”, isn’t it?

Comment: Yes, you need the present perfect because you are still experiencing the repercussions.

Comment: There are lots of sentences where you could use either *spent her life* or *has spent her life*, but I think the only time *has spent* is wrong is when the person is dead. And if the verb has repercussions on the present moment, you should use *has spent*.

Comment: Thank you both SO much!

Comment: For the example, you could say that your study of cookery [**precluded**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/preclude) you from following your passion. For the question title, an event that has repercussions in the future can be described as being [**momentous**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/momentous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to talk about an action as something that caused something, then the action is functioning as a noun (it's a thing that is doing stuff). A noun formed from a verb is a gerund. So it would be "Spending my life ..."